# Trying to run both hadoop MapReduce commands and linux commands in shell script

Tags: java, shell, hadoop

I have a shell script like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
echo "RUNNING HADOOP PROGRAM"
cd /home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop
sudo rm -R /tmp/*
sudo rm -R /app/*
cd
sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp
sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
sudo chmod 750 /app/hadoop/tmp
hadoop namenode -format
/home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
jps
hadoop dfs -mkdir -p ~/Downloads/hadoop/input
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Desktop/iris.arff ~/Downloads/hadoop/input
hadoop jar ~/Desktop/try.jar 2 weka.classifiers.trees.J48  ~/Downloads/hadoop/input ~/Downloads/hadoop/output
/home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
```

I am invoking this script in my java program like this

```
    public class UIinput 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {

    //      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh");
    new ProcessBuilder("/home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh");
               Process process=pb.start();      
               InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
               InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

               String line;

               System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
                  Arrays.toString(args));

               while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
               {
                 System.out.println(line);
               }
    }
}
```

My start-all.sh,stop-all.sh and echo commands That are getting executed present in the script are getting executed but other commands are not.My output is like

```
Output of running [] is:no jobtracker to stop
localhost: no tasktracker to stop
no namenode to stop
localhost: no datanode to stop
localhost: no secondarynamenode to stop
RUNNING HADOOP PROGRAM
starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/hduser/Downloads/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-ubuntu.out
stopping jobtracker
localhost: stopping tasktracker
no namenode to stop
```

Can anyone help me?I when I run my java code i want all of the commands to be executed in the shell script.
Thank you

Comment: If script is failed you can find root caused by reading/consuming also system.err using process.getErrorStream() as you have already done for System.out.

Comment: I tried that.But it is not printing anything..@mbsau

Comment: I do not see any errors in the output given. Technically all the commands should execute from the script. Do you see any errors while the script execution?

Comment: No errors.But few lines in the script are not executed.I checked script by script.other than start and stop scripts and echo no other command is executed@sras

Comment: sudo commands maybe cause this. If you are able to run program as a root You can run java program.Don't forget remove sudo in script. By the way Can hduser run jps at shell?

Comment: i am able to run jps in command line as hduser.@mbsau

Comment: Firstly try to execute your java program as a root.e.g sudo java packagename.UI arg1 arg2.. Don't forget remove sudo from script file. What is the result? Secondly I wonder whether you launch your java program remotely( ssh host '/my/java/program' ) or local. If you define  commands(jps, hadoop) at .bashrc you cannot call commands for remote executions.

Comment: Yeah.I tried echo 'passwd'| sudo command..and it worked..Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Run your script with below code and see the problem details in system out

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class CommandLineExecutor {

    public final int EXEC_OK = 0;
    public final int EXEC_FAILED = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CommandLineExecutor cmd = new CommandLineExecutor();
        String[] script  = new String[]{ "/home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh"};
        boolean joinToProcess = true;  //Main threads waits process finished.
        int result = cmd.execute(script, joinToProcess);
        System.out.println( result == 0 ? "Script succesfully run" : "Script failed" );

    }

    public int execute(String[] cmd, boolean joinToProcess) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("executing cmd: "+concat(cmd));
            proc = runtime.exec(cmd);
            StreamProcessor errorStreamProcessor = new StreamProcessor(proc.getErrorStream());
            StreamProcessor outputStreamProcessor = new StreamProcessor(proc.getInputStream());
            errorStreamProcessor.start();
            outputStreamProcessor.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return EXEC_FAILED;
        }
        try {
            int result = EXEC_OK;
            if(joinToProcess)
             result = proc.waitFor();
            return result;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error at executing command: " + concat(cmd) );
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        return EXEC_FAILED;

    }

     public static String concat(String[] array) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (i > 0)
                    buffer.append(' ');
                buffer.append(array[i]);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }



     class StreamProcessor extends Thread {

            private InputStream inputStream;

            public StreamProcessor(InputStream is) {
                this.inputStream = is;
            }

            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    while (true) {
                        String s = br.readLine();
                        if (s == null)
                            break;
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Few of the commands are showing this error                         /home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh: 13: /home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh: jps: not found
/home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh: 14: /home/hduser/Desktop/initial.sh: hadoop: not found

Comment: run the java from root user. java code does not have the privileges for executing the commands as i understood